AttributeError when filtering streams in Pytube
I'm trying to use the pytube library to download YouTube videos. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to filter the streams. Here is the code I'm using (just the necessary part of it):
from pytube import YouTube
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip
import os

link = input("Enter link here: ")
filename = input("Enter desired filename here: ")

filename = filename.replace('"', '').replace('&', 'and')

url = YouTube(link)

print("downloading....")

video = url.streams.filter(res="2160p", mime_type="video/webm").first() 

When I run this code, I get the following error:
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\YouTube.py", line 15, in <module>
    video = url.streams.filter(res="2160p", mime_type="video/webm").first()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 411, in get_throttling_plan
    transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'


For me it works when I search for the video link in the "Inspect view" (Chrome) while I watch a Youtube video and then paste it into your programme
For example this link: https://www.youtube.com/e4aa1f20-23f1-4fed-b31c-a81c8a33d1ec
instead of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-nMKJ5J3Uc&ab_channel=MrBeast
--edit--
Try this instead:
from pytube import YouTube
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip
import os

link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
filename = input("Enter desired filename here: ")
filename = filename.replace('"', '').replace('&', 'and')

url = YouTube(link)

print("downloading....")

video = url.streams.get_highest_resolution()


Sadly, your solution doesn't work for me. The weird thing is that the exact same script worked just fine yesterday.

@Kasmori Can you try the code above? If it doesn't work either, I would say there is an issue with your pytube.

So, out of nowhere, it worked again. I'm not sure what the problem was, but waiting fixed it. Thank you for your help.
